# php look in database for data not working

Tags: php, sql

i'm making a quiz webpage connected to a datbase, but my code isn't working.
i have this code:

```
    $query = "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $question = mysql_result($result, 0);
    echo $question;
```

it should look in my table for a question with id 1 and then echo the question, the possible answers and the correct answer.
the column names are: id, question, a, b, c, d and correct

here is how it looks like in phpmyadmin, 
since im not allowed to post images, here is a link to the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNJkd.png

can someone help me???

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. You should be using PDO or mysqli_*

Answer (score 1):

```
$question = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $question['question'];
```

OR

```
$question = mysql_result($result, 0, 'question');
echo $question;
```

should do.

Aside of that, `mysql_*`-functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php)

Comment: Where did you read the mysql_result is returning an array by default

Comment: @RoyalBg: Sorry confused the function with `mysql_fetch_array()`, corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$query = "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $question = mysql_result($result, 0);
    echo $question['question'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $question = mysql_result($result, 0, 'question');
    echo $question;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query = "SELECT `question` FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$question = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $question['question'];

/*
or for get the correct answer
you can just: echo $question['correct'];
//*/
```